# Using a variable for pandas read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I use the below code to find a .csv file with a certain pattern. I would then like to pass it into the read_csv() function, but it seems that it only accepts a string. What can I do to pass my variable "csv_file" into the function?

Code:

```
csv_file = glob.glob('******* Output.csv')
```

Tried

```
print(csv_file)
['1815910 Output.csv']

d = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
```

TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: Have you looked at what `csv_file` actually is? i.e. what `glob.glob` returns

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `glob.glob` returns a list. Why are you using glob in the first place if there is only one possible file?

Comment: TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: You need to include the _full_ traceback in the question

Comment: I am using glob because this will be executed using different .csv files at different time that all follow a similar pattern but do not have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

`glob.glob` return list of files matched with your regex, but read_csv need a file name, so you could iterate all the files

```
csv_files = glob.glob('******* Output.csv')

#it will get list of dataframes
d = [pd.read_csv(csv_file) for csv_file in csv_files]
```